# Trying to get the char code of ENTER key

Tags: java, gwt

I have this this code:

```
newSymbolTextBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
  public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
      System.out.println("foo =" + KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER);
  System.out.println("bar =" + event.getCharCode());
  }
});
```

When I press ENTER I get this output:

```
foo =13
bar =
```

I expected a value after `bar =`. Any idea?

Comment: Is this using the standard Java API or some other library like GWT?

Comment: your class names are strange.  I don't think there is a KeyPressEvent class in Java.  What are you using?

Comment: @berry120 Yes! I'm using GWT, I don't know that could count..I'm just starting with Java an GWT.

Comment: @tirengarfio In that case you should tag your question as such otherwise people assume it's using something like swing! I've retagged it now as above.

Comment: @tirengarfio See Justin's answer below, and issue 5558 http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5558

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value is, in fact, there. The reason you don't see anything is because the character is a carriage return. The carriage return, I believe, just moves the next line (you can google it's exact function). If you google "ascii table" you will see that the 13 you get from `KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER` corresponds with CR, the carriage return character.

Comment: @Justin, I tried that but it is returning 0. I get my code from here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/manageevents.html. Is Google tutorial wrong?.

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast the char that is returned by `getCharCode()` . chars and ints are one of the same. You can directly compare them without any trouble. Example:  'A' == 65   evaluate to true. The only reason you aren't seeing anything after `bar =` is because the carriage return character (int value = 13) doesn't correspond with any visible character, just a new line.

Comment: Tyler, chars and ints are the same internally but are output differently. If this wasn't the case, you'd never be able to `println` an integer that corresponds to an ASCII character. By casting to int, you're telling the output routine "I want to display the integer value, not the character representation."

Comment: Yea I understand what you're saying, I just figured that was not needed in this case because he had already printed the integer value of the char. Very good explanation though :)

Comment: @tirengarfio, A bit late on the reply to your question: Yes, the Google tutorial is wrong. The issue ticket (see my answer below) was accepted a month and a half ago and it's still not fixed; hopefully they'll resolve this error in the documentation soon.

Answer (score 8):

You need to either use `event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode()` or switch to `KeyDownHandler`.

```
newSymbolTextBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
  public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
      System.out.println("foo =" + KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER);
      System.out.println("bar =" + event.getNativeKeyCode());
  }
});
```

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5558

Answer (score 0):

`KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER` is the integer value of the Enter key. `event.getCharCode(`) is the character representation, so it would show as a newline after `bar =`

Answer (score 0):

In windows with java 7 returns 10 for both cases.

And to display the number value of a char you need cast it to int.

```
System.out.println((int) e.getKeyChar());
```

Answer (score 0):

As it sounds weird, but try to imagine that
new line means '\n' as a character or the character is "Enter" button on the keyboard.
So, in code it look like this:

```
        if(event.getKeyChar()=='\n'){
            System.out.println("You just pressed ENTER!");
        }
```