# GUI wait for keyboard "enter" and continue display

Tags: java, swing, events, user-interface

I have a JAVA card game, which show four cards at each round.

Currently, the stop between each round is waiting for a \n input in console. But I'd like to change it to waiting for a keyboard "enter" on the GUI.

Following is my current code. Please let me know how should I change it?

Millions of thanks!!!

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class Game {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.shuffle();
        int aGame = 4;

        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card> ();

        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            cards.add(deck.deck.get(i));
            if(aGame == 1) {
                System.out.println(deck.deck.get(i).toString());
                System.out.println("Start!!!");

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Calculating 24!");
                GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2, 2);
                f.setLayout(grid);

                f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });

                for(Card c: cards){
                    f.add(new LoadImageApp(c));
                }
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
                cards.clear();

                while (true) {
                    char c = (char) System.in.read();
                    if (c == '\n') {

                        f.setVisible(false);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                aGame = 4;
                if(i == 51) {
                    deck.shuffle();
                    i = -1;
                }
            }
            else if(aGame == 4) {
                System.out.println("Calculate based on the following four cards!");
                System.out.println(deck.deck.get(i).toString());
                aGame --;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(deck.deck.get(i).toString());
                aGame --;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: You can use KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215955/trying-to-get-the-char-code-of-enter-key

Comment: If its a java based Desktop application, you can implement KeyListener

Comment: Could you please kindly give me some idea how to implement the KeyListener? Thanks!

Comment: @Manish noooo - in Swing we don't use keyListeners, we use keyBindings

Comment: @SanyamGoel see my comment to Manish

Answer (score 3):

For Swing based applications key events should be handled using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). However it may not be apparent to the end user that ENTER is required. A more UI centric approach is to use a dialog for this purpose

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Press ENTER to continue");
```

Using console based read methods such as `InputStream#read` is another source of confusion for users. Use a `JTextComponent` such as a `JTextField` to read user input in Swing applications.

Answer (score 3):

If the GUI element accepting the values is a `JTextField`, it is possible to add an `ActionListener` that will typically respond when the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>

### Other tips

#### 1)

```
                f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
```

Change that to:

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperaiton(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Or better..

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperaiton(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

The first will have the same effect as what was, but the second will also check there are no non-daemon threads running prior to exit.

#### 2)

Do not try to mix GUIs and the command line together.  The way you go about writing an application for either is significantly different.