# Enter key code for Java key event handlers

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, keyboard, keyboard-events

I am writing a code for a simple web browser for my school project. Currently I want to have the code to be able to visit the site entered in the url when pressed the enter key. All of my buttons work (back, forward, refresh, etc) but I cant seem to get the keyboard event handlers working.

The error that I am currently faced with in the event handler is that its not getting the code for the enter key. I already looked at many different sources like this one [Trying to get the char code of ENTER key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215955/trying-to-get-the-char-code-of-enter-key) but they havent been much help to solve my issue.

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
package application;
    

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebHistory;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class Main extends Application {
    private BorderPane root;
    private WebView webView;
    private WebEngine webEngine;
    private HBox addressBar;
    private HBox statusBar;
    private Text domain;
    private WebHistory history;
    
    private final String homePage = "https://google.ca";
    
    //------------------------------------------------------
    
        private void setupAddressBar() {
            addressBar = new HBox();
                Button home = new Button("Home");
                Button back = new Button("<--");
                Button forward = new Button("-->");
                Button refresh = new Button("Refresh");
                
                TextField url = new TextField();
                addressBar.getChildren().addAll(home,back,forward,refresh,url);
                
                
                class HomeButton implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
                    
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        homePage();
                    }
                }
                
                
                class BackButton implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
                    
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        
                        back();
                        
                    }
                }
                
                class ForwardButton implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
                    
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        
                        forward();
                        
                    }
                }
                
                class RefreshButton implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
                    
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        
                        refreshPage();
                    }
                }
                
                
                class KeyboardPressedHandler implements EventHandler<KeyEvent>{
                    
                    @Override
                    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                        
                        KeyCode key = event.getCode();
                        
                        if(key == Keycode.ENTER ) {
                            loadPage();
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                        
                
        
                HomeButton homeButton = new HomeButton();
                home.setOnAction(homeButton);
                
                BackButton backButton = new BackButton();
                back.setOnAction(backButton);
                
                ForwardButton forwardButton = new ForwardButton();
                forward.setOnAction(forwardButton);
                
                RefreshButton refreshButton = new RefreshButton();
                refresh.setOnAction(refreshButton);

                KeyboardPressedHandler pressedHandler = new KeyboardPressedHandler();
                url.setOnKeyReleased(pressedHandler);
                
        }
            
        //----------------------------------------------------
        private void setupStatusBar() {
            statusBar = new HBox();
                domain = new Text("google.ca");
                Text separator = new Text("|");
                Text copyright = new Text("JavaFX -- All Rights Reserved.");
                statusBar.getChildren().addAll(domain, separator, copyright);
        }
        
        //-------------------------------------------------
        public void setupWebView() {
            webView = new WebView();
            webEngine = webView.getEngine();
            webEngine.load(homePage);
        }
        
        
        
        public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
            webEngine = webView.getEngine();
            loadPage();
            
        }
        
        public void loadPage() {

            webEngine.load("http://" + domain.getText());
        }
        
        public void homePage() {
            webEngine.load("http://google.ca");
        }
        
        public void refreshPage() {
            webEngine.reload();
        }
        
        public void forward() {
            history = webEngine.getHistory();
            ObservableList<WebHistory.Entry> entries = history.getEntries();
            history.go(1);
            domain.setText(entries.get(history.getCurrentIndex()).getUrl());
        }
        
        public void back() {
            history = webEngine.getHistory();
            ObservableList<WebHistory.Entry> entries = history.getEntries();
            history.go(-1);
            domain.setText(entries.get(history.getCurrentIndex()).getUrl());
        }
        
    
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        root = new BorderPane();
        //---------------------------------
        this.setupAddressBar();
        this.setupWebView();
        this.setupStatusBar();
        //----------------------------------
        root.setTop(addressBar);
        root.setBottom(statusBar);
        root.setCenter(webView);
        
        //----------------------------------
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        //stage.getFullScreen(true);
        stage.setWidth(1200);
        stage.setHeight(1000);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Browser");
        stage.show();
;       
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't set the keyboard hander at the end of `setupAddressBar`. Maybe adding this will help:
`KeyboardPressedHandler pressedHandler = new KeyboardPressedHandler();
url.setOnKeyReleased(pressedHandler);`
Also, it is `KeyCode.ENTER` not `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER`

Comment: @MKAl thanks, that seemed to fix the errors but the enter key still doesnt work  for some reason

Comment: still don't see you adding/setting the pressed handler to any node  .. Even when you do: be aware that key events are delivered only to the focused node! BTW: this is _not_ a [mcve] as required .. which has to mind the __M__! Nothing unrelated: if you have problems with a particular handler, everything except two or three nodes wired to that handler is unrelated - as is visual fluff ;)

Comment: This is an xy problem.  You don’t need a key handler at all.  The text field will consume the key events when it has focus, so they are not going to bubble up to your handler.  Instead provide an action handler on the text field the same way you set action handlers on the buttons.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for your response. I did end up adding the event handler to the node but for some reason it doens't work and I'm now more confused. I edited my code on the post if that helps.

Comment: 1) strip it down to the most minimal to demonstrate the __exact__ problem nothing else 2) be sure you understand/learn to understand the previous comments: the part about the focused in mine and the default key handling by @jewelsea